# How to 'grow' an iFrame depending on the size of its contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm loading the iFrames dynamically and some pages are 'taller' than others. I'd like the iFrame to grow accordingly. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by jquery.
Parent page code:

```
<iframe id='ifrm' />
```

Script on iframe page:

```
function alertSize() {
  var myHeight = 0;
  if (typeof (parent.window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
    //Non-IE
    myHeight = parent.window.innerHeight;
  } else if (parent.document.documentElement
    && (parent.document.documentElement.clientWidth || parent.document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
    //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
    myHeight = parent.document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  } else if (parent.document.body && (parent.document.body.clientWidth || parent.document.body.clientHeight)) {
    //IE 4 compatible
    myHeight = parent.document.body.clientHeight;
  }
  //window.alert( 'Height = ' + myHeight );
  return myHeight;
}

function AssignFrameHeight() {
  var theFrame = $("#ifrm", parent.document.body);
  var frameHeight1 = getIframeHeight('ifrm');
  var frameHeight2 = $(document.body).height();
  if ($(document.body)[0]) {
    if ($(document.body)[0].bottomMargin)
      frameHeight2 += Number($(document.body)[0].bottomMargin);
    if ($(document.body)[0].topMargin)
      frameHeight2 += Number($(document.body)[0].topMargin);
  }
  if (frameHeight1 > frameHeight2) {
    theFrame.height(frameHeight1 - 20);
  } else {
    if ($.browser.msie)
      theFrame.height(frameHeight2);
    else
      theFrame.height(frameHeight2 + 50);
  }
}

function getIframeHeight(iframeName) {
  //var iframeWin = window.frames[iframeName];
  var iframeEl = parent.document.getElementById
    ? parent.document.getElementById(iframeName)
    : parent.document.all
      ? parent.document.all[iframeName]
      : null;
  if (iframeEl) {
    iframeEl.style.height = "auto"; // helps resize (for some) if new doc shorter than previous
    //var docHt = getDocHeight(iframeWin.document);
    // need to add to height to be sure it will all show
    var h = alertSize();
    //var new_h = (h - 148);
    //iframeEl.style.height = h + "px";
    return h;
    //alertSize();
  }
}
```

Reassign height after postback:

```
function pageLoad() { // MS AJAX - UpdatePanel
  AssignFrameHeight();
}

$(document).ready(function() { // jQuery
  AssignFrameHeight();
});
```

Comment: nice. loads of browser hacks ;)

Comment: Works in: IE 4-8, FF 3, Opera 10, Chrome 4.0, Safari (last version)

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do something like

```
document.getElementById('your-iframe').height=new_height;
```

But if you really need to have an iframe grow depending on the content then I suggest you try another html element as an iframe might not be what you need.

Answer (score -2):

try using width:100%; height:100% and apply them on your iframe element