# Setting ASP.NET update panel to be 100% of its parent container?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

How can I set an ASP.NET update panel to be 100% of its parent container?
Right now it's height is just big enough to fit its contents. It's display mode is block.
I added a

```
style="height: 100%"
```

attribute to the updatepanel tag, but the parser complained that the style tag is undefined for `asp:UpdatePanel`.

Comment: I would surround the UpdatePanel by a `div`(or nest a `div/Panel` inside the ContentTemplate)  and apply the style to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`height: 100%` is very bad style solution. This won't work after resizing or similar user actions.

All you can do - set the height automatically by javascript.
See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872967/how-to-grow-an-iframe-depending-on-the-size-of-its-contents/2872993#2872993) (it is about the iframe, but javascript is easily updated for your needs)

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the `asp:UpdatePanel` inside of a `asp:Panel` and use that to control the size.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hacky but you could do something like this to style an `UpdatePanel`

```
<head>
...
<style type="text/css">
    #<%=UpdatePanel1.ClientID %> {height:100%;}
</style>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    ...
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use C# backend to control style of update panel in at the page_load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   UpdatePanel.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("height","100%");
 }
```