# Opera does not change the height of the page. Why?

Tags: jquery, html, css, opera

1. Open http://188.232.30.182/ in opera
2. One click left arrow (It is possible and right, but you need 2 clicks)
3. Scrolling page bottom.

Why is there a blank space and how to fix it? In other browsers, all is well

Answer (score 1):

Probably some issue with Opera.

I also checked with Firefox 5, IE 9 and Google Chrome 14. Seems to work out fine.

Try Upgrading Opera's version. Check View/Display options, which manage size.

Probably some addon is interfering.

So report the bug and you will find it out!

Comment: Anyways, this not much of a technical issue to be posted.

Comment: And probably pertains to your browser settings.

Comment: I use latest version opera (11.50)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some height css to `body`, and adding `overflow: hidden`. This will remove scroll bars. You may be able to do `height: 100%`, or you may have to find the actual height

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Opera saves the height of your element from the first page load, during which your table has 5 rows of countries.

Try to reset height of your main page after click is performed.

Comment: @user499596 Try to use script from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872967/how-to-grow-an-iframe-depending-on-the-size-of-its-contents/2872993#2872993), just change the `iframe` element to that you need.